# Version control Conda environments for Python projects

Tags: python, version-control, mercurial, anaconda

I use the Anaconda distribution of Python. I am wondering how to best version control Conda environments for Python projects.

Each of my projects is a Mercurial repository. They use specific Python packages at specific versions. What is the best way to put these environments into the repos such that as long as a computer has Anaconda installed, things will work smoothly without re-setting up the environments?

Comment: Suggest `conda list` run at pre-commit time and included in the commit.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `conda list --export` to export the list of packages and `conda install --file` to reinstall them. You can also check out [conda-env](https://github.com/conda/conda-env), which lets you keep track of the packages you want in an environment.yml file, which you can keep under version control.